# SQL JOIN to get the compare two values/row from table "A" and the same row from table "B"

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have two tables with the following rows

Table A (transaction)

```
 Order       Seller      Customer    
 1           300         500
```

Table B (Persons)

```
PersonID          FullName        
300               Peter White
500               Scott Bold
```

I want a result like this

```
Order      Seller        Customer     FullName (Seller)      FullName  (customer)     
1          300           500          Peter White            Scott Bold
```

I've tried multiple things however which makes more sense is a join a table twice, however I'm getting:

> Ambiguous column name

This is SQL Server 2019.

Basically I'm looking to retrieve info from the same table instead of creating additional tables. Is that possible? If yes, how do you do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: JOIN table B twice, one time for seller, and one time for customer. Use table and column aliases.

Comment: Please post the query otherwise it's hard for us to guess what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jarlh wrote in comment:

```
select t.order, t.seller, t.customer, sel.fullname, cust.fullname
from transaction t
join persons sel -- sel is an alias to persons table
  on sel.personid = t.seller
join persons cust
  on cust.personid = t.customer;
```

Query with `join` will return the result as long as both seller and customer exist in `persons` table -- here it should as source table names `transactions` :).

Answer (score 0):

I have another form of query it still join table B twice.

This is archaic syntax which I don't recommend but for beginner know the concept of JOIN:

```
select t.*,B.FullName as FullName  (customer)  from
(

select A.Order,A.Seller,A.Customer,B.FullName as FullName(Seller) 
    from A,B where A.Seller=B.PersionID
) t, B where t.Customer=B.PersionID
```

The proper way of JOIN:

```
select t.*,B.FullName as FullName  (customer)  from
(
select A.Order,A.Seller,A.Customer,B.FullName as FullName(Seller) 
        from A JOIN B ON A.Seller=B.PersionID
) t JOIN B ON t.Customer=B.PersionID
```

Hoping this can help you.

Comment: Why are you choosing to use archaic syntax and not proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: I couldn't know JOIN even I read the document of SQL when I was beginner, but I knew archaic syntax. After I have concept from archaic syntax I know what JOIN doing.  I choose archaic syntax for let beginner know quickly. But you are right , I will update my post. Thanks.